# CSS3 PIE conflicting with :first-child

Tags: internet-explorer, css, css3pie, css-selectors

I'm using [CSS3 PIE](http://css3pie.com/) to add suppport for border-radius to IE8 and earlier, and it's conflicting with a :first-child selector.

Basically, I have three list items floated left. Each one has a left margin of 10px, except for the first one, which I set to 0:

```
#steps li {
    border-radius: 10px;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 10px;
}
#steps li:first-child {
    margin-left: 0;
}
```

When I apply PIE to the `#steps li` selector to add support for border-radius, the first list item is redrawn with the left margin set back to 10px, as if the `#steps li:first-child` selector isn't there. I can tell it's due to PIE redrawing the element, because it briefly flashes in the correct position and then shifts over 10px a split second later.

I've tried applying PIE to both selectors, but that doesn't make a difference, and I'm unable to find anything pertaining to first-child on the PIE support forums.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look at the official forum over at [CSS3 PIE Forums - IE :first/last-child overwritten](http://css3pie.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=77)

The end result is that you need to add

```
#steps css3-container:first-child + li, 
#steps li:first-child {
    margin-left: 0;
}
```

Comment: Since CSS3 PIE is there anyway, maybe even enable CSS3 selectors, and use `#steps li:first-of-type` ;)

Comment: Oh, it doesn't? That sucks :(

Comment: @BoltClock *chuckle*.. maybe you are confusing it with [`ie-css3.js`](http://selectivizr.com/) ?

Comment: I wasn't - I was hoping PIE would polyfill selectors too. But hey, Selectivizr looks cool.